# Wordpress Events Manager getting category name by category id

Tags: wordpress

What is the EM syntax for getting the EM category **id** based on the EM category **name**? In the regular WP category taxonomy it is

```
get_cat_ID($cat_name)
```

Is there something similar for EM categories?

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

get_term_by('name', $cat_name, EM_TAXONOMY_CATEGORY);

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by

I suggest you bring this up on our forums, since we don't actively provide support on here.

http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/events-manager

Comment: Thanks! 

Yes, sure by next time I will bring some of my concerns in your forums